# object reference not set to an instance when functions call in unit test(intellitest)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api2, intellitest

i have problem when i call any function within my unit test controller class,
when i run the test, its give error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

i am not sure what i am missing here or i do not know i do call function in unit test, i am using intellitest using visual studio 2015 enterprise edition

here my code

1. /// This class contains parameterized unit tests for AccountFinFilesController

   ```
   [TestClass]
   [PexClass(typeof(AccountFinFilesController))]
   [PexAllowedExceptionFromTypeUnderTest(typeof(ArgumentException), AcceptExceptionSubtypes = true)]
   [PexAllowedExceptionFromTypeUnderTest(typeof(InvalidOperationException))]
   public partial class AccountFinFilesControllerTest
   {

       /// <summary>Test stub for .ctor(ISmallBizRepository)</summary>
       [PexMethod]
       public AccountFinFilesController ConstructorTest(ISmallBizRepository repo)
       {
           AccountFinFilesController target = new AccountFinFilesController(repo);
           return target;
           // TODO: add assertions to method AccountFinFilesControllerTest.ConstructorTest(ISmallBizRepository)
       }

       /// <summary>Test stub for Delete(Guid, Guid)</summary>
       [PexMethod]
       public HttpResponseMessage DeleteTest(
           [PexAssumeUnderTest]AccountFinFilesController target,
           Guid id,
           Guid deletedby
       )
       {
           HttpResponseMessage result = target.Delete(id, deletedby);
           return result;
           // TODO: add assertions to method AccountFinFilesControllerTest.DeleteTest(AccountFinFilesController, Guid, Guid)
       }

       /// <summary>Test stub for GetAccountFinFilesTable(Guid, Guid)</summary>
       [PexMethod]
       public IQueryable GetAccountFinFilesTableTest(
           [PexAssumeUnderTest]AccountFinFilesController target,
           Guid firmid,
           Guid id
       )
       {
           IQueryable result = target.GetAccountFinFilesTable(firmid, id);
           Assert.IsNotNull(result);
           return result;
           // TODO: add assertions to method AccountFinFilesControllerTest.GetAccountFinFilesTableTest(AccountFinFilesController, Guid, Guid)
       }

       /// <summary>Test stub for GetAccountFinFilesTable(Guid)</summary>
       [PexMethod]
       public IQueryable GetAccountFinFilesTableTest01([PexAssumeUnderTest]AccountFinFilesController target, Guid firmid)
       {

           IQueryable result = target.GetAccountFinFilesTable(Guid.Parse("75165ae3-cbae-e511-b0bf-00259076695a"));
           Assert.IsNotNull(result);
           return result;
           // TODO: add assertions to method AccountFinFilesControllerTest.GetAccountFinFilesTableTest01(AccountFinFilesController, Guid)
       }

       /// <summary>Test stub for Post(AccountFinFilesTable, Guid, Guid)</summary>
       [PexMethod]
       public HttpResponseMessage PostTest(
           [PexAssumeUnderTest]AccountFinFilesController target,
           AccountFinFilesTable obj,
           Guid firmid,
           Guid createdby
       )
       {
           HttpResponseMessage result = target.Post(obj, firmid, createdby);
           return result;
           // TODO: add assertions to method AccountFinFilesControllerTest.PostTest(AccountFinFilesController, AccountFinFilesTable, Guid, Guid)
       }

       /// <summary>Test stub for Put(AccountFinFilesTable)</summary>
       [PexMethod]
       public HttpResponseMessage PutTest([PexAssumeUnderTest]AccountFinFilesController target, AccountFinFilesTable obj)
       {
           HttpResponseMessage result = target.Put(obj);
           return result;
           // TODO: add assertions to method AccountFinFilesControllerTest.PutTest(AccountFinFilesController, AccountFinFilesTable)
       }
   }
   ```
2. WebAPI controller class

   ```
     public class AccountFinFilesController : BaseApiController
     {
       private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
       public AccountFinFilesController(ISmallBizRepository repo)
           : base(repo)
       {
       }

       // GET api/AccountFinFiles
       /// <summary>
       /// GetAccountFinFilesTable
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="firmid"></param>
       /// <param name="id"></param>
       /// <returns></returns>
       [HttpGet]
       public IQueryable GetAccountFinFilesTable(Guid firmid, Guid id)
       {
           log.Info("GetAccountFinFilesTable API -- firmid=" + firmid + "&id=" + id);
           return TheRepository.GetAccountFinFile(firmid, id);
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// GetAccountFinFilesTable
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="firmid"></param>
       /// <returns></returns>
       [HttpGet]
       public IQueryable GetAccountFinFilesTable(Guid firmid)
       {
               log.Info("GetAccountFinFilesTable API -- firmid=" + firmid);
               return TheRepository.GetAccountFinFile(firmid);
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// update AccountFinFilesTable
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="account_finfilestabledm"></param>
       /// <returns></returns>
       [HttpPut]
       public HttpResponseMessage Put(AccountFinFilesTable obj)
       {
           try
           {
               var updatedEntity = TheModelFactory.Parse(obj);

               if (updatedEntity == null)
               {
                   log.Error(MessagesHelper.recordnotfound + "File_ID: " + obj.File_ID);
                   Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Could not read AccountFinFilesTable from body");
               }

               var originalEntity = TheRepository.GetAccountFinFileByPrimaryKey(obj.File_ID);

               if (originalEntity == null || originalEntity.File_ID != obj.File_ID)
               {
                   log.Error(MessagesHelper.recordnotfound + "File_ID: " + obj.File_ID);
                   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotModified, "AccountFinFilesTable record not found");
               }
               else
               {
                   updatedEntity.File_ID = obj.File_ID;
               }

               if (TheRepository.Update(originalEntity, updatedEntity) && TheRepository.SaveAll())
               {
                   log.Info(MessagesHelper.updatesuccess + "File_ID: " + obj.File_ID);
                   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, TheModelFactory.Create(updatedEntity));
               }
               else
               {
                   log.Error(MessagesHelper.updateerror + "File_ID: " + obj.File_ID);
                   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotModified, "Could not update to the database.");
               }

           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               log.Error(ex.Message + " " + obj.File_ID);
               return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
           }

       }

       /// <summary>
       /// add new record to AccountFinFilesTable
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="account_finfilestabledm"></param>
       /// <param name="firmid"></param>
       /// <param name="createdby"></param>
       /// <returns></returns>
       [HttpPost]
       public HttpResponseMessage Post(AccountFinFilesTable obj, Guid firmid, Guid createdby)
       {
           try
           {
               obj.FirmId = firmid;
               obj.ClientId = createdby;
               obj.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

               var entity = TheModelFactory.Parse(obj);

               if (entity == null)
               {
                   log.Error(MessagesHelper.recordnotfound + " " + firmid + " " + createdby);
                   return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Could not read AccountFinFilesTable from body");
               }
               else
               {
                   if (TheRepository.Insert(entity) && TheRepository.SaveAll())
                   {
                       log.Info(MessagesHelper.savesuccess + " " + firmid + " " + createdby);
                       return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, TheModelFactory.Create(entity));
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       log.Error(MessagesHelper.saverror + " " + firmid + " " + createdby);
                       return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Could not save to the database.");
                   }
               }

           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               log.Error(ex.Message + " " + firmid + " " + createdby);
               return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
           }
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// delete record from AccountFinFilesTable
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="account_finfilestabledm"></param>
       /// <param name="deletedby"></param>
       /// <returns></returns>
       [HttpDelete]
       public HttpResponseMessage Delete(Guid id, Guid deletedby)
       {
           try
           {
               var entity = TheRepository.GetAccountFinFileByPrimaryKey(id);

               if (entity == null)
               {
                   log.Error(MessagesHelper.recordnotfound + "File_ID: " + id);
                   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
               }

               if (TheRepository.DeleteAccountFinFile(id, deletedby) && TheRepository.SaveAll())
               {
                   log.Info(MessagesHelper.deletesuccess + "File_ID: " + entity.File_ID);
                   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
               }
               else
               {
                   log.Error(MessagesHelper.deleteerror + "File_ID: " + entity.File_ID);
                   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Could not delete the record.");
               }

           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               log.Error(ex.Message + "File_ID: " + id);
               return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
           }

       }

   }
   ```
3. error

[image: object reference not set to an instance of an object]

please help/guide or provide me a complete solution according to my scenario, i will provide more detail if required. thanks for your valuable time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Add a TestInitialize function with that attribute and initialize your class variables there. Then at the point you can use your initialized member variable throughout your tests.

Add a CleanUp function as well. See [TestInitializeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testinitializeattribute.aspx)

Comment: thanks for your answer, please explain me in detail, how to use in code, provide me code example.